# write excel file to many folders in directory using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to write an excel file to many folders ( folder* ) under D:\ and loop over them to further process individually.

i tried the following code for long time ..

```
  srcFolders = dir('D:\folder*');
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
    xlswrite('srcFolders\filename.xls', srcFolders(folder).name,'Sheet1', folder_range); 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to write different sets of data to a Excel file and were just having some trouble. If that's not accurate comment and let me know.

```
%Just generating some arbitrary data
data = arrayfun(@(m,n) rand(m,n), randi(50, 9, 1), randi(50, 9, 1), 'uni', 0);

%The base file path
path = 'D:';

%The pattern used to choose the folders
folderPattern = 'folder*';

%The files you want to write to
srcFiles = {'A', 'B', 'D'};

%And the extension
ext = '.xlsx';

%Get the path of the folders
srcFolders = dir(fullfile(path, folderPattern));
srcFolders = fullfile(path, {srcFolders.name});

%Construct the full file path
fullPath = cellfun(@(f) fullfile(f, strcat(srcFiles(:), ext)), srcFolders, 'uni', 0);
fullPath = vertcat(fullPath{:});

%Write the data to the files
for i = 1:length(fullPath)
    xlswrite(fullPath{i}, data{i})
end
```

Edit:

Based on OP's feed.

Note for the second overhaul. I didn't test this and I'm done. This was way to much for a single question and you are abusing the way this website is supposed to work.

```
%The base file path
path = 'D:';

%Relative reference to reference images
ImageRefLocations = {'Ref\RefI1.jpg', 'Ref\RefI2.png', 'Ref\RefI3.jpg'};
%Base Image location
baseImage = fullfile(path, ImageRefLocations(:));

%The pattern used to choose the folders
folderPattern = 'folder*';

%The image extension
[~, ~, ext] = unique(cellfun(@(f) fileparts(f), baseImage, 'uni', 0));

%The excel extension
ExcelExt = '.xlsx';

msg = {' = no'; ' = ok'};

i0 = cellfun(@(f) imread(f), baseImage, 'uni', 0);

%Get the path of the folders
srcFolders = dir(fullfile(path, folderPattern));
isDir = [srcFolders.isdir];
srcFolders = {srcFolders(isDir).name}';
PathedFolders = fullfile(path, srcFolders);
excelFiles = fullfile(path, strcat(srcFolders, ExcelExt));

for i = 1:length(PathedFolders)
    f = PathedFolders{i};
    Images = cellfun(@(x) dir(fullfile(f, ['*', x])), ext, 'uni', 0);
    Images = vertcat(Images{:});

    if isempty(Images)
        continue
    end

    Images = {Images.name}';
    [~, ImageNames, ~] = cellfun(@(x) fileparts(x), Images, 'uni', 0);
    ImageList = fullfile(f, Images);

    match = zeros(size(ImageList));

    for j = 1:length(ImageList)
        image = imread(ImageList{j});

        for k = 1:length(i0)
            if ~all(size(image) == size(i0{k}))
                continue
            end

            match(j) = all(image(:) == i0{k}(:));

            if match(j)
                continue
            end
        end
    end

    matchMessage = strcat(Images, msg(match + 1));

    xlswrite(excelFiles{i}, matchMessage)
end
```

Comment: thank you sir for your reply , 
for data there are no matter if any data i have to write , but my concern about how i can write a single excel file that file its ( write ) on all folders with name of folder* ( folder 1 , folder 2 , .... folder n ) and all folders include same excel file name but each one include different data , 
my problem now how can write excel file in each folder , 
suppose there is an images in each folder for example folder 1 contain 2 images , folder 2 contain 1 image , folder 3 contain 3 images ...

Comment: Just so you know. If this is your issue then you should probably asked the question you asked and then a second question with the image processing stuff.

Comment: However, it sounds like you want to go through folders 1, 2, ..., n which may contain some images. You want to go through all the images in the folder and see if they are the same. If they are, then you want to write two Excel  files where the names match the image file names and the data is the image. Is that accurate?

Comment: thank you sir for reply .. no problem its only write an single excel file ... but this file its only for single folder .. and its write this file in same folder has parsed ,, for example if now start with folder 1 and this folder contain 2 images its create excel file with name of result inside folder 1, data in that file contain : for example ( its exam with my test image )
image 1 = ok 
image 2 = no 
then go to nest folder 2 and repeat same process ... finally 
i hope to get result excel files , each one store in the folder when checked has been done ,,, its this possible ,,, thank you

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want. You have some reference image (I'll call this `image0`). Then in each folder you want to compare Image1, Image2, ..., ImageN to `image0`. You then want to summarize the results of the comparison by writing to an Excel file (which has the same name as the folder) (in A1) `'Image 1 = ok'`, (in B1) `'Image 2 = no'`, ...,  (in the Nth row, 1st column) `'Image N = ok'`. Is all that accurate?

Comment: And unless you post your code with all of the variables defined I can't know why you are getting the error. Also you didn't say what like this is on.

Comment: for the above code i use your code and i got error ,,, when this code its correct implement without errors i modified to my requirement ..
thanks again

Comment: thank you very much ... this is really very good and smart solutions thank you a lot ... thank you with my best regards ,

Comment: only small note sir ,.. in future if i need to compare 5 images with images in folders * and print same result output ... its possible ... ? if possible please edit and update your second code for this reason ,, thank you a lot sir

Comment: what is the wrong in the second code , its my final issue ... error as follow 
((
Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.

Comment: any help please sir ... i modified you code only small changes ,,, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833406/%D9%8Bwrite-images-result-in-excel-file-based-on-template-color-histogram-comparison